# Targeting the toggled state

Tags: jquery

I am new to all of this but i am trying to target the state of my button once i have pressed it and my hidden div slideToggles down. I want the button to appear as it does when i hover over it but when i move my mouse of and click into the new slideToggled div it goes back to its original state. I was thinking something along the lines of

ifToggled //then do this

else //remain in orginal state,

but i cant find any examples of how to target this 'active or toggled' state.

This is my code so far.
HTML - i have 6 of these buttons arranged 3 by 2 and the slidetoggle div pops out in the centre of the top 3 and bottom 3, all working fine.

```
<a href="#!" class="active">
      <span id="product1">
      </span>
</a>
```

JQuery. All works fine except for the commented out bit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#product1").click(function(event){
                    $("#product2box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $("#product3box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $("#product4box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $("#product5box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $("#product6box").slideUp('slow', function() {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    $("#product1box").stop().slideToggle(1000);

                    // if ($("product1box").isToggled) {
                    //  //want to show hover state as active class
                    // } else {
                    //  ///want to show normal state
                    // }

                    return false;
                });
                });
                });
                });
                });
                });
```

Comment: The drop down part isnt working on jsfiddle but you can see where it is, the gap there opens and closes as i click on each product box and i want that hover state of the colors to show up on the relevant button once it has been toggled if that makes sense? @filoxo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".producthandler").click(function() {
        var ctx = $(this);
        var productboxId = ctx.children().eq(0).attr("id");

        ctx.toggleClass('active');
        $("#" + productboxId + "box").stop().slideToggle(1000);

        $(".producthandler").each(function() {
            var ctx = $(this);
            var producthandlerId = ctx.children().eq(0).attr('id');

            if (productboxId !== producthandlerId) {
                ctx.removeClass('active');
                $("#" + producthandlerId + "box").slideUp(1000); 
            }   
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @FiLeVeR10 this was my solution here.

Answer (score 0):

**No need to call each by ID**

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="product">
    <span>...</span>
</a>
...

<div class="productbox">...</div>
....
```

jQuery

```
$('.product').each(function(i) {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');//toggle active class
        $('.productbox').eq(i).stop().slideToggle()//current up/down
            .siblings('.productbox:visible').stop().slideUp();//siblings up

        return false;//prevent link
    });
});
```

**You can see it in action [Right Here »](http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/xw947bhv/)**

Comment: Ah yes, i do need to do some simplifying everywhere haha have never coded at all before so getting there slowly by teaching myself.

Comment: If you check the jsfiddle link i posted above you will see what im essentially trying to do, i hvnt tried your code in there yet, will it activate that hover state when the div drops down?

Comment: Just tried this now, my divs no longer drop down upon click with this code @FiLeVeR10

Comment: Ok thank you @FiLeVeR10 im just going with if it works i'll roll with it haha. So i know its not perfect but my index.html file is working perfectly in my browser so far haha

Comment: Oh cool thanks so much! @FiLeVeR10 look forward to seeing it!

Comment: Oh duh ofcourse!  I noticed the hover state isn't showing anymore? which is my main thing, i want that hover state of the color to show when i click on the main product buttons so the viewer can make a connection to which product they are viewing etc as the logo is in that top blue bar greyed out until they hover (or hopefulyl click) so the full product is shown in colour.. does that make sense? @FiLeVeR10

Comment: @charlotteg just target active with *.product.active*, apply ur styles and you should be set. (I used it to add a red border on the bottom in the fiddle, just refresh to see) I removed a lot of the css, just to demonstrate an easier way to write it, so you'll have to go through all of your code and update it. Heading to bed man, hope it helps.

Comment: @charlotteg does this fix your problem?